# Map generic observable list to generic list

Tags: typescript, generics, rxjs, typescript-generics

Is it possible to map an array of type `[Observable<string>, Observable<number>]` to `[string, number]` using generics?

```
function example(obs: Observable<any>[]): any[] { }
```

Desired Behaviour:

```
example(of(''), of(0)) // typeof [string, number];
```

I know rxjs makes use of `ObservedValueOf<O>` and function overloading for `combineLatest`, but I don't want to follow the same overloading approach.

Comment: Are you asking about the type signature or the implementation?

Comment: Observables represent streams, i.e. they emit from 0 to infinite values over time. So, when you say you want to map `[Observable<string>, Observable<number>]` you need to be more specific. How many values emit each Observable? What happens if one emits and the other not, which is something that will happen since they can easily be asynchronous? What happens when one completes or errors?

Comment: @jcalz, yes. I am looking for the type signature for the function.

Comment: @Picci, I want to pass an infinite array of observables to the function and have the function's return type specify an array of the observable results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The call signature for `example()` should probably be using a [mapped type applied to an array](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html#mapped-types-on-tuples-and-arrays):

```
declare function example<T extends any[]>
    (...obs: { [K in keyof T]: Observable<T[K]> }): T;
```

Here the type `T` represents the output array/tuple type, and the input parameter `obs` maps `T` so that each element is wrapped in `Observable<>`.  [Inference from mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#inference-from-mapped-types) will allow `T` to be inferred from the type of `obs` when you call `example()`:

```
const result = example(of(''), of(0));
// const result: [string, number]
```

That's the type you wanted.

---

Note that while the question is not about the implementation here, I'm concerned that you will run into problems.  I'm no expert in rxjs, but it seems that in general you wouldn't be able to synchronously convert an `Observable<X>` to an `X` because the observable might not have any value of type `X` ready for you when you call `example()`.   I suppose you can have `example()` throw an error if the inputs don't have values ready?  It seems more reasonable to have `example()` convert `[Observable<string>, Observable<number>]` into `Observable<[string, number]>`, where the output observable could wait until each input had a value before outputting. Just something to be mindful of.

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.1.3#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgeQEYGcCmUBuBDVAG0zgF84AzKCEOAcigA8ArdOgbgFgAoAE0wDGhPFBIUArgDsBMYBElwIFADwAVAHwAKAHS6RAc3QAuOJtUBKANoBdcybRZcBYmvU8e-ISLFSZchZiMeOAuqnCBMJiSvOhweJIAnjZu3HBpprraEBgmSJYA0nDACgDWmAlKcKrW9hjY+ESYagXW6mR2VVzcPALy6PCi6OKE8AC84UEhmJpKmnR05gA0ihSaAAzm5l0A9NtwvZL9cIPDMCaW-VDF+suS4iCo2Nbu3EA)

Comment: Just to give clarity as to why I need to map observables to a synchronous result of type array: I have multiple subscriptions I want to open on a single store, when all the observables return their current state though the use of `combineLatest`, I call a callback passing all the states of the `combineLatest` result.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the best you can do is to mix one of the functions that expects arrays of Observables as input (e.g. `combineLatest` or `forkJoin`), `toPromise` method of Observable and `async\await`, something like

```
async function example<T, Q>(obs: [obs1: Observable<T>, obs2: Observable<Q>]) { 
  return combineLatest(obs).toPromise()
}

const o1 = of('')
const o2 = of(1)
async function test() {
  const res = await example([o1, o2])
}
```

In the above example `res` would be of type `[string, number]`.

Having said that I would strongly discourage to use such a mechanism and in general to turn Observables (which are streams with potential infinite notifications) into Promises.

Observables are streams and they expect to be `subscribe`d. When you `subscribe` to them you pass them up to 3 functions, one to describe what to do when the Observable emits (`next`), one to describe what to do if it errors (`error`), one to describe what to do when it completes (`complete`). And this is the way you should use them.